# Capture screen and stream to rtmp server using LFLiveKit

Tags: ios, xcode, video-streaming, rtmp

I am trying to use the [LFLiveKit](https://github.com/LaiFengiOS/LFLiveKit) sdk to send rtmp streams to server. I tried this to stream the pixel buffer like so,

```
var Lsession: LFLiveSession = {
  let audioConfiguration = LFLiveAudioConfiguration.defaultConfiguration(for: LFLiveAudioQuality.high)
  let videoConfiguration = LFLiveVideoConfiguration.defaultConfiguration(for: LFLiveVideoQuality.low3)
  let session = LFLiveSession(audioConfiguration: audioConfiguration, videoConfiguration: videoConfiguration)
  return session!
}()

let stream = LFLiveStreamInfo()
stream.url = "rtmp://domain.com:1935/show/testS"
Lsession.pushVideo(frame.capturedImage)
```

How can I initialize the session with screen capture? Any pointers?

Comment: and how do you capture the screen of the iphone?

Comment: Hi @Pavan K could you please tell us how you capture the camera view and send that to stream URL??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by camera view - `(frame.capturedImage)` this is the camera view from an arkit scene view.

Comment: If you want the view with ar content overlayed then you can use `snapshot()` to get the `UIImage` and then convert it to pixel buffer and stream it over I suppose

Comment: by camera view, I mean the feed that the user can see on the camera view. whatever the camera captures and shows on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to set captureType in the session initilization like so,

```
let session = LFLiveSession(audioConfiguration: audioConfiguration, videoConfiguration: videoConfigurationcaptureType: LFLiveCaptureTypeMask.inputMaskVideo)
```